# Three.js texture not load properly?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I use OBJLoader to load the 3D model and I want to put a wood texture but the texture was not load properly or maybe not render properly(I dunno). [Here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVvIz.png) 
[This the image of the wood texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXYuT.jpg)

Please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

**Here's the code:**

```
<script>

  var container;
  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
  var container, stats;
  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
  var globalObject;
  var text;

  init();
  animate();


 function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
  camera.position.z = 10;

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

  //scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
  scene.add( ambient );

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
  directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
  scene.add( directionalLight );

  //manager
  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
  };

  //model
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
  loader.load( 'image/table.obj', function (object) {
    //store global reference to .obj
    globalObject = object;


  object.traverse( function (child) {
      if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
          child.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'image/texture.jpg')
          /*child.material.map.x = 100 / 800;
          child.material.map.y = 100 / 800;*/
          child.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
  });

  object.position.y = 0;
  scene.add( object );
});

//render
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
 }

function onWindowResize() {
windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 }

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;
}

//animate
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
render();
}

function render() {
//camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
//camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
        //camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();


</script>
```

// This the MTL file 
 Blender MTL File: 'None'
 Material Count: 1

newmtl Material.002
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd wood2.jpg

Comment: What is the problem? The color of the texture, or its position? In three.js the object color and the texture are blended together, so you can get the original texture color if you change the material color to white.

Comment: Does your .obj have correct UV coordinates?

Comment: the image you posted has the texture applied to it but with blue color. can you post your .mtl file? your lights dont seem to be blue.

Comment: Hello kovacsv, I think the problem is the color, I don't know why the color of the image is blue.

Comment: Hello 2pha, what is UV coordinates ?

Comment: Hello, gaitat I already post the .mtl file above. what's wrong with lights ?

Answer (score 0):

In three.js the object color and the texture colors are blended together, so you can get the original texture color if you change the material color to white.

When you set a map to the material, try to change the original ambient and diffuse color to white. The concrete code depends on the type of the material. Something like this:

```
child.material.ambient = 0xffffff;
child.material.diffuse = 0xffffff;
```